# How to configure a GKE load balancer for a golang tcp server?

Tags: go, tcp, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After deploying a golang server container and gke load balancer I can successfully connect to the external ip of the load balancer, but no data reaches the server container.

It works as expected when I run the server container locally and point the client at localhost. I changed it to serve http requests and it worked fine with the same kubernetes manifests. However, if I try to serve both tcp and http (on different ports) then **neither work** on gke but again works fine locally. So I suspect it probably has something to do with either how I configured the load balancer or how I'm listening for tcp connections in the server breaks something when running on gke but not locally.

K8s Service Manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: steel-server-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: steel-server
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: tcp
    port: 12345
    targetPort: 12345
```

K8s Deployment Manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: steel-server-deployment
  labels:
    app: steel-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: steel-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: steel-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: steel-server
        image: gcr.io/<my-project-id>/steel-server:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 12345
          name: tcp
```

Relevent Go TCP Server Code

```
server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":12345")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Couldn't start up tcp server: ", err)
}
```

Comment: If you send traffic to the container directly, does it work? Try ssh to a node, run 'sudo toolbox bash' then test connectivity to your pod (bypass the service). Do you get a response?

Comment: Also, are you using an Ingres for http? If so, is the a different nodePort service? Your container should not stop serving traffic on http just because you added another device for tcp

Answer (score 0):

Can you try first with `kubectl get svc` so you get to know which ports are open with load balancer as you got external ip from GCP as `type:loadbalancer`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: steel-server-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: steel-server
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: tcp
    port: 80
    targetPort: 12345
```

Try with this service config i change port to 80 while target port of same as container port.

Comment: i get this when i run kubectl get svc after changing to port 80
kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.35.240.1     <none>           443/TCP        2d
steel-server-service   LoadBalancer   10.35.251.155   35.232.215.231  80:32093/TCP   6m
same result, my client can connect to the external ip but my server container doesnt receive any packets

Comment: Check for load balancer you have created it is global,TCP,ntework load balancer or which type of LB it is.